# How to print XOR integer values in python?

Tags: python, hex, ascii

*EDIT: It turns out the problem is written in a confusing way. EACH byte has to be XOR'd against the single character.*

I've trying to solve [this](https://cryptopals.com/sets/1/challenges/3) and have googled about encoding, binascii and printing in python but can't get this to work:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import binascii

xoredString = 0x1b37373331363f78151b7f2b783431333d78397828372d363c78373e783a393b3736

for argument in range(ord("A"), ord("z")):
    result = xoredString ^ argument
    print(binascii.unhexlify("%x" % result).decode('ascii')) #Should be printing some word or phrase
```

(Edited the print argument) So now it prints values like the following (only the last character varies. Its due to the XOR I guess)

```
7316?x413=x9x(7-6<x7>x:9;7w
```

Which I guess is completely wrong...can anyone point where I could be making a mistake?

Comment: `binascii.a2b_hex` takes a _string_ that represents a hex value, but you're giving it a number, the inaptly-named `xoredString` that isn't a string. Hex values are just numbers that you've specified with a different literal than usual; they don't have a unique type.

Comment: So how can I make 0x12 (or 18) become "12"? is that possible with the standard library? I mean, at some point before doing the XOR I have to turn both arguments into ints and that is screwing up my script :/

Comment: `hex` is a built-in function.

Comment: print(binascii.a2b_hex(hex(result))) tried that but didn't work...Non-hexadecimal digit found. Also with unhexlify. Same error. So I guess the issue is the "x" at position 1. I could take it out via slicing but that is extremely...non pythonic?...that didn't work either. Thanks anyway for the tip.

Comment: An option you can always do is: convert xoredString to binary String, convert argument to binary String, code your own XOR function on two strings, shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: Thats a nice idea! Will try it. Thanks!